# Implementing a zonejs-less angular 8 project

Tags: angular, angular-changedetection, zonejs

I was migrating my angular project to angular 8 and came across these two articles :

- https://blog.angularindepth.com/boosting-performance-of-angular-applications-with-manual-change-detection-42cb396110fb
- https://blog.angularindepth.com/do-you-still-think-that-ngzone-zone-js-is-required-for-change-detection-in-angular-16f7a575afef

I'm now interested in implementing having a project without zonejs.

I ran `npm remove zone.js`, then I removed `import 'zone.js/dist/zone';` in `polyfill.js` and then I added `, {ngZone: 'noop'}` to my `bootstrapModule` call in my `main.ts`.

And whith that my app ran.

but of course now I should manually add the points where change detection are required and this is where these guides fail woefully.
perhaps they are outdated (published in 2018 and 2017 respectively, which is only 1-2 years ago).

the methods they (and the other google hits you can get on `.tick()`) reference classes that don't exist or classes that do exist but don't have `.tick()`.

[image: error message : property 'tick' does not exist on type 'typeof ApplicationRef']

What's a real world example for angular 8-9, es6, ECMAScript, type implementation of manual change detection?

For example right now I'm missing one on my landing page which is supposed to redirect after token reception :

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.loading = true;
    // reset login status
    if (this.window.navigator.userAgent != 'fakeAgent') {
      this.tryConnect();
      // Maybe tigger changedetect here?
    }
  }

  tryConnect(withLogout?: boolean) {
    this.error = '';
    this.loading = true;
    let uid = $('input#uid');
    if (!this.authenticationService.isOAuth && uid && uid.val()) {
      const data = {...};

      this.http.post(AppGlobal.API_URL + 'auth/tokens', data).subscribe(
        res => {
          // console.log(res);
          // Maybe tigger changedetect here?
          this.authenticationService.setToken(res.json());
          this.autologin();
        },
        err => {
          // console.log(err);
          this.authenticationService.setToken('unknown');
          this.autologin();
        }
      );
    }
  }

  autologin() {
    this.authenticationService.autologin().subscribe(
      result => {
        this.success = 'Connected';
        this.currentUser = this.authenticationService.getCurrentUser();
        let afterlogin = localStorage.getItem('afterlogin');
        let afterloginparams: any = JSON.parse(
          localStorage.getItem('afterloginparams')
        );
        if (!afterloginparams) {
          afterloginparams = {};
        }
        localStorage.removeItem('afterlogin');
        localStorage.removeItem('afterloginparams');
        if (afterlogin) {
          this.router.navigate([afterlogin], {queryParams: afterloginparams});
        } else {
          this.router.navigate(['/']);
        }
        // OR TRIGGER CHANGE DETECTION HERE ?
      },
      error => {
        let afterlogin = localStorage.getItem('afterlogin');
        let afterloginparams: any = JSON.parse(
          localStorage.getItem('afterloginparams')
        );
        if (!afterloginparams) {
          afterloginparams = {};
        }
        localStorage.removeItem('afterlogin');
        localStorage.removeItem('afterloginparams');
        if (afterlogin) {
          this.router.navigate([afterlogin], {queryParams: afterloginparams});
        } else {
          this.router.navigate(['/']);
        }
        this.finishedOnError('User not found');
      }
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to call change detection on **the whole tree of Angular views** then you should be using `ApplicationRef` instance like this:

```
constructor(private appRef: ApplicationRef) {} 

someMethod() {
  this.appRef.tick();
}
```

But I would advise you using `cdRef.detectChanges()` instead.

```
constructor(private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {}    

someMethod() {
  this.cdRef.detectChanges();
}
```

This will call change detection on **the current component and on all its children**.

Comment: thank you, will I have to add hundreds of these on an already mature project or are the instances of manual change detect rare?

Comment: Yes, you have to carry of all those cases when you need to update UI. If your mature project is completely reactive then you can patch some `subscribe` method once to call change detection. Having strong state management system can also help here

Comment: sorry that was Chinese to me. are you saying I can create a refactored implementation of triggering  changedetect using and intercept or something of the sort? 

Also is getting rid of zone.js something you would personally recommend?

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about how you call detectChange only in one place by having some kind of interceptor. If you know how your data flows then it should be easy to get rid of zone.js but in most cases I would suggest keeping zonejs.